# WX library Rect

Tags: python, opencv, wxpython

I am in the middle of using OpenCV along with the WXLibrary to create a Rect object for image processing.

Here is our code
    for contour in contours:

```
       #print cv2.boundingRect(contour)
       #rec = Rect(a)
       a= cv2.boundingRect(contour)
       rec = wx.Rect(a)
```

and our error is:

```
  traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/OpenCV(c++).py", line 149, in <module>
processImage()
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/OpenCV(c++).py", line 101, in processImage
   rec = wx.Rect(a)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py",          line 1145, in __init__
   _core_.Rect_swiginit(self,_core_.new_Rect(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: in method 'new_Rect', expected argument 1 of type 'int'
```

Syntax-wise, it seems fine. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

wx.Rect's constructor doesn't directly accept the output from OpenCV. Try passing each parameter in separately.

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
rect = wx.Rect(x, y, w, h)
```

Comment: or just `rec = wx.Rect(*a)`